# JSONParser doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

This type of JSON Object is coming to my Android device :

> {"Successful":true,"Value":{"Materials":[{"MaterialID":999999,"Type":1,"StockNo":1,"Weight":1}]}}

I'm trying to parse that like this :

```
public String parseMaterial(JSONObject object){
try{
    JSONArray objectArray = object.getJSONArray("Value");
    }
catch(JSONException e){
    Log.d("Jsonparser=>error", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What I get in Logcat is :

> D/Jsonparser=>error: Value:{"Materials":[{"MaterialID":999999,"Type":1,"StockNo":1,"Weight":1}]}

What am I doing wrong here? Why does the program fall in to catch block? Thanks.

Comment: you need to use getJsonObject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cause `Value` is not a Json Array